# What is the difference between a shared formula and an array formula?

Tags: excel, excel-2007, formula

Excel defines shared formulas and array formulas. What is the difference?
My understanding is that array formulas are now obsolete. Is this true?
Is it possible to transform array formulas into shared formulas?

Comment: Maybe you should create a Superuser login and move this question there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shared formulas are simply a more efficient means of storing formulas.

Array formulas add significant functionality and are definitely not obsolete. For example, the MMULT function can return multiple values. To get these multiple values into multiple cells you must use an array formula. Array formulas are entered into a range of cells by selecting the range, typing the formula, and then pressing CTRL+SHIFT+ENTER.

Answer (score 3):

Look at **section 4.8** of [**The Microsoft Excel File Format**](http://sc.openoffice.org/excelfileformat.pdf#page=96) (PDF ref) from OpenOffice:

> An array formula (BIFF2-BIFF8) and a shared formula (BIFF5-BIFF8) is a formula spanning over a range of cells. Array
>   formulas are handled different from single cell formulas in a spreadsheet. Shared formulas are only an optimisation to
>   decrease the file size, they are not distinguishable from other cell formulas. Naturally an array formula cannot be a
>   shared formula at the same time. Shared formulas are created for instance when filling a cell range from a single formula
>   cell.
>
> In general an array or shared formula is stored only once in a file, either in the ARRAY record (➜5.4) for array formulas,
>   or in the SHAREDFMLA record (➜5.94) for shared formulas. These records are part of the Formula Cell Block
>   (➜4.7.2). They immediately follow the first FORMULA record (➜5.50) for this range<sup>20</sup>. All array or shared formula cells contain a reference to the formula data. This reference (tExp token, ➜3.10.1) consists of the cell address of the top left cell of the range. In this way each formula cell can be associated with its formula data.
>
> If a formula returns a string value, a STRING record (➜5.102) follows the FORMULA record normally. In the case of
>   array and shared formulas, this STRING record follows the ARRAY or SHAREDFMLA record.
>
> <sup>20 <sub>For shared formulas the first FORMULA record may not be the top-left cell of the range. It is possible to overwrite single cells of a shared formula range without invalidating the shared formula itself (the remaining formula cells).</sub></sup>